# Does Devi bhagavatam contain interpolation?

Tags: devi-bhagavata-purana, interpolation, commentary

Does Devi bhagavatam contain interpolations?
Did anyone write a commentary on it?

Comment: Whether some text has interpolations or not is a difficult thing to determine. So, its possibly opinion based. The rest of the question is alright.

Comment: All texts we have today except probably the Vedas contain interpolation. Best example being Valmiki Ramayana

Comment: In which part of Ramayana as interpolation

Comment: @PashamVishnuVardhanGoud the last chapter. Chapter 7 is an additional chapter

Answer (score 2):

It does. Imo every Purana contain atleast some interpolations.

Check verse 4:20:36-37:

"O King! When Mahādeva, being infatuated with Kāma, went into the forest of Bhṛgu and becoming naked, began to copulate, the ascetic Bhṛgu, seeing him in that state, exclaimed “O You are very shameless” and cursed Him thus :-- Let your penis drop off just now. Mahādeva, then to satisfy his thirst for passion, began to drink the water of the lake Amrita Vapī, dug by the Dānavas."

Then also these verse 7:39:21-30:

"To preserve My Commandments, I have created the Brāhmaṇa and the Kṣattriya castes. My secrets are all embodied in the Śrutis. For that reason, the words of the Śrutis are no doubt to be known and observed by the sages. O Mountain! When the Dharma (righteousness) declines and the Adharma (unrighteousness) reigns supreme, I then manifest Myself in the world as Sākambharī, Rāma, Kṛṣṇa and others. Therefore, the Devas, the preservers of the Vedas, and the Daityas, the destroyers of the Vedas are classified. Whoever does not practise according to the Vedas I have created many hells for their lessons. When the sinners hear of those hells, they get extremely terrified. The king should banish those stupid persons from his kingdom and the Brāhmins should not talk with them nor take them in their own lines nor when partaking of food, those who forsake the Vaidic Dharma and go for shelter to another Dharma. The Śāstras that are extant, as contrary to the Śrutis and Smritis, are all Tāmasa Śāstras, Mahādeva has framed these Vāma, Kāpālak, Kaulaks, Bhairava and such like Śastras for fascinating the people; else he has no object in framing them. Those Brāhmaṇs that were burnt up by the curses of Dakṣa, Śukra, Dadhīci and were banished from the path of the Vedas, it is for delivering them, step by step that Mahādeva has framed the five Āgamas, Śaiva, Vaiṣṇava, Śaura, Śātta and Gānapatya Śāstras."

These verses opposing agamas.

[image]

[image]

I noticed these only. I think this is done by someone who has misunderstandings about agamas and was biased towards vedas.

Namah Shivaay

Comment: Sir I think Devi Bhagavatam is wrong here. Because Tantras were there from beginning of cycle and Agamas arent just created to uplift Bramhins who were cursed by Shiva but to whole world and Non Dwijas. Vaishnavas say Pancharatra was indeed a part of Vedas and its open to all. Let me ask Ikshwaku sir and Rickross Sir and let you know

Comment: @Sethu yes sir that's why i have listed it among interpolated verses. I don't think Maharshi Veda Vyas will write such things and even if he does, he would surely give solid reason for it. But even reason here is vague. So, it is interpolation by someone who had biased opinion and used to hate tantra.

Comment: @rudra sir even lord shankaracharya tells agamas are not truth bez agamas tells about dvaita .

Comment: @Pasham ever heard of 64 Bhairav agamas?